# Strings in C: Why does this work?

Tags: c

I'm sorry for asking something that probably seems a little inane as it is apparently not broken but my (newbie) understanding of how C handles string literals tells me that this should not work...

```
char some_array_of_strings[3][200];
strcpy(some_array_of_strings[2], "Some garbage");
strcpy(some_array_of_strings[2], "Some other garbage");
```

I thought that C prevented the direct modification of string literals and that was why pointers were used when dealing with strings. The fact that this works tells me I am misunderstanding something.

Also, if this works, why does...

```
some_array_of_strings[1]="Some garbage"
some_array_of_strings[1]="Some garbage that causes a compiler error due to reassignment"
```

not work?

Comment: Hint: The "cpy" part of `strcpy` means "copy".

Comment: Is it creating a temporary pointer behind the scenes or something?

Comment: No, it's copying into memory referenced by the pointer you gave it (the first argument).

Comment: There are no temporary pointers behind the scenes in C — especially not in this context.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: To be painfully clear, there are no temporary pointer *objects*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be careful with the phrase "array of strings". A "string" is not a data *type* in C; it's a data *layout*. Specifically, a string is defined as

> a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the
>   first null character

An array of `char` may *contain* a string, and a `char*` pointer may *point to* (the first character of) a string. (The standard defines a pointer to the first character of a string as a *pointer to a string*.)

```
char some_array_of_strings[3][200];
```

This defines a 3-element array, where each of the elements is a 200-element array of `char`. (It's a 2-dimensional array, which in C is simply an array of arrays.)

```
strcpy(some_array_of_strings[2], "Some garbage");
```

The string literal `"Some garbage"` refers to an anonymous statically allocated array of `char`; it exists for the entire execution of your program, and you're not allowed to modify it.  The `strcpy()` call, as the name implies, *copies* the contents of that array, up to and including the terminating `'\0'` null character, into `some_array_of_strings[]`.

```
strcpy(some_array_of_strings[2], "Some other garbage");
```

Same thing: this copies the contents `"Some other garbage"` into `some_array_of_strings[2]`, overwriting what you copied on the previous line.  In both cases, there's more than enough room.

You're not modifying a string literal, you're modifying your own array by copying bytes *from* a string literal (more precisely, from that anonymous array I mentioned above).

```
some_array_of_strings[1]="Some garbage";
```

This doesn't just "not work", it's illegal. There is no assignment of arrays in C.

Let's take a simpler example:

```
char arr[10];
arr = "hello"; /* also illegal */
```

`arr` is an object of array type. In most contexts, an expression of array type is implicitly converted to a pointer to the array object's first element. That applies to both sides of the assignment: the object name `arr` and the string literal `"hello"`.

But the pointer on the left side is just a pointer *value*. There is no pointer object. In technical terms, it's not an *lvalue*, so it can't appear on the left side of an assignment any more than you could write `42 = x;`).

(If the array-to-pointer conversion didn't happen, it would still be illegal, because C doesn't permit array assignments.)

Some more detail on the issue of arrays on the left side of assignment:

The contexts where an array expression *doesn't* decay into a pointer are when the array expression is:

- an operand of the unary `sizeof` operator;
- an operand of unary `&` (address-of) operator; or
- a string literal in an initializer used to initialize an array object.

The left side of an assignment isn't any of those contexts, so in:

```
char array[10];
array = "hello";
```

LHS is, in principle, converted to a pointer. But the resulting pointer expression is no longer an lvalue, which makes the assignment a constraint violation.

One way to look at it is that the expression `array` is converted to a pointer, which then makes the assignment illegal. Another is that since the assignment is illegal, the whole program is not valid C, so it has no defined behavior and it's meaningless to ask whether any conversion does or does not happen.

(I'm playing a little fast and loose with my use of the word "illegal", but this answer is long enough already so I won't get into it.)

Recommended reading: Section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com); it does an excellent job of explaining the often bewildering relationship between arrays and pointers in C.

Comment: I always wanted to ask... Do arrays not decay to pointers when appear to the left of the assignment operator? I mean, practically, it doesn't matter whether you assign to an array or to a non-modifiable value as both are illegal, but which one of the two is it? Any standard reference to disambiguate this case?

Answer (score 3):

you aren't modifying the string literal, you are using it as a source to copy it into your array of characters.   Once the copy is finished,   your string literal has nothing to do with  the copy in your array.  You are free to then manipulate the array.

Comment: I was thinking of it as being like `char whatever="Blah blah"` when what it is doing is more like `whatever[0]='b' whatever[1]='l'`

Comment: @cwm - when you write `char *txt = "Hello";` you have that - a pointer to the string literal array.

Answer (score 1):

From your definition, `char some_array_of_strings[3][200];` indicates that `some_array_of_strings` is an `array` of 3 elements, each of which is itself an `array` of 200 characters or strings of length `200` characters.

```
strcpy(some_array_of_strings[2], "Some garbage");
strcpy(some_array_of_strings[2], "Some other garbage");
```

In these 2 statements, you are actually **copying** the content from one `char pointer` to another `char pointer` which is valid. `some_array_of_strings[2]` is actually similar to `char[200]` which is similar to `char *`.

```
some_array_of_strings[1]="Some garbage";
some_array_of_strings[1]="Some garbage that causes a compiler error due to reassignment";
```

Here, you are **assigning** a `char *` like `"Some garbage"` to a `char[200]` i.e. `some_array_of_strings[1]` which is not supported. The difference lies in `assigning` and `copying` the content.

Answer (score 1):

```
some_array_of_strings[1]="Some garbage"
some_array_of_strings[1]="Some garbage that causes a compiler error due to reassignment"
```

In the first line you assign some_array_of_strings[1] to a string literal so the address of some_array_of_strings[1] or &some_array_of_strings[1] points to a string literal. So in the second line when you try to reassign some_array_of_strings[1] it gives you the error.

It is just as Keith and Fred have said, with strcpy you are only copying the characters of the string literal into you array.

Answer (score 1):

`some_array_of_strings[2]` is an array of 200 chars.

When it's used in most expressions, it "decays" (fancy word for converts) into a pointer to the first element of the array.

`strcpy(some_array_of_strings[2], "Some garbage");` then copies `"Some garbage"` character by character into that array of 200 chars, by making use of the pointer to the first element of the array and advancing it one by one.

In most expressions `"Some garbage"` is a pointer to an array of chars containing those respective characters plus a string termination character (`'\0'`).

`some_array_of_strings[1]="Some garbage"` on the other hand attempts to assign a pointer (to the string) to the constant/non-modifiable pointer to the first element of 200 chars, which is also illegal (like doing `1=2;`)